# Arms of Parallal Plate Capacitor

Tags: capacitance

In case if Parallel Plate Capacitors, is it necessary for the two plates to be equal in length? If yes why?
And if they were not equal, what would be the problem?

Comment: Well, what do you think? Can the two plates ever be _exactly_ the same size and _exactly_ parallel? So, what happens?

Comment: There would be no problem, you would simply waste expensive metal on little gain in capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Any two objects which are insulated from each other have a capacitance.  The bigger the objects are and the closer together they are, the more capacitance they have.

The most efficient way to pack a lot of capacitance into a small device is to use an insulating dielectric film to hold two wide, thin conductors just barely apart from each other over a large area.  So that is what "capacitors" look like in practice, and that is how we draw them to study how they work.  But if you add extra metal onto one of the plates of a capacitor and leave the other unchanged, it will increase the capacitance by an almost negligible amount (unless the extra area is wrapped around the back of the other plate or something fancy like that...).